# Who are these DC superheroes?

Tags: dc, character-identification

Besides Batman, Superman , Wonder Woman and Green Lantern, who are these superheroes?[image]

Comment: red tornado looks like the Avatar with a sunburn.

Comment: Here's another [version of the OP's picture](http://ifanboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Justice-League-of-America-Vol.-2-7-2007.jpg) that contains the full frame from the comic panel. In it, the left & right frames are not obscured.

Comment: What I am surprised by is not a single one of you mentioned the name of this quintessential super-team, The Justice League. In addition, each of these photographs shows a particular iteration of the Justice League: The original Justice League of America, Justice League Detroit, Justice League Unlimited, Justice League of America (expanded ranks) and the JLA (the branding for the comic series at the time).

Comment: @Thaddeus Maybe you can tell us why Martian Manhunter is in every one of those background pictures, but not in the new one?

Comment: Because DC wanted to legitimize the inclusion of the Wildstorm superhero group, The Authority (Stormwatch), which was integrated into the New 52 universe. The Martian Manhunter is leading Stormwatch. - http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20140108004502/marvel_dc/images/8/8f/Stormwatch_Vol_3_1.jpg

Comment: @MikeEdenfield Avatar Aang was was heavily influenced by Red Tornado (note the 3 other Red robots with elemental powers in the Red Tornado universe)

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - Martian Manhunter's absence from this version of the League can't be explained by his leading Stormwatch in the New 52 (which launched in 2011), as this version is from 2006.

Comment: You do recognize I know this already. I was answering the question regarding the New Justice League, not the one in the image.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze - Ah - I had interpreted "not in the new one" as "not in the new picture being taken in the image", not as "not in the JLA in the New 52".

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Top: Green Lantern, Wonder Woman, Superman, Batman, Black Canary

Bottom: Hawkgirl, Black Lightning, Speedy, Vixen, Red Tornado

Comment: To be fair, at the time Roy Harper was Red Arrow, not Speedy...and I'm not just saying that to increase the rep on my answer...really...I'm not...

Comment: Black Lightning, and not Static Shock?

Comment: @TylerH It is definitely Black Lightning. Static Shock has a lightning bolt on his chest.

Comment: @JackBNimble Oh. I thought that was a lightning bolt on Black Lightning's chest. I guess it's DC's version of Static Shock

Comment: @TylerH: Static is part of the extended DC universe. And Black Lightning far predates him.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Cool, I wasn't aware of Black Lightning's existence

Comment: The character's name is Static, not Static Shock.  Static Shock was just the name of his animated series.  And, as others have said, that is not him.

Answer (score 223):

The foreground image is the initial line-up of the Justice League team seen in *Justice League of America* (2006). The image comes from issue #7 of that series.

The photographs seen on the wall around those team members show the membership of the team from other times in the group's history.

**Front and Center:**

- Green Lantern (Hal Jordan)
- Wonder Woman
- Superman
- Batman
- Black Canary
- Hawk Girl
- Black Lightning
- Red Arrow (Roy Harper, otherwise known as Speedy or Arsenal)
- Vixen
- Red Tornado

**[Top left framed image:](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070910204402/marvel_dc/images/0/0b/Justice_League_of_America_Archives_4.jpg)** - This represents the original membership of the Justice League of America, as they first appeared in *The Brave and the Bold* (1955) #28 (cover-dated February/March 1960):

- Martian Manhunter
- Batman
- Aquaman
- Wonder Woman
- Superman
- The Flash (Barry Allen)
- Green Lantern (Hal Jordan) - *obscured*

**[Middle left framed image:](http://www.comicvine.com/images/1300-1682220/)** - This represents the Justice League's membership during the "satellite era" (when they moved from a headquarters in a cave to a satellite headquarters, circa *Justice League of America* (1960) #78-232). Technically, Martian Manhunter and Snapper Carr were not members of the League during this time, but both made occasional appearances. I was unable to find this image, but I suspect it appeared somewhere around issue #200 (in which both Martian Manhunter and Snapper Carr appeared, and which had art by George Perez, who looks like the artist of this piece).

- Batman
- The Elongated Man
- Firestorm
- Hawkgirl
- Green Lantern (Hal Jordan)
- Snapper Carr ~
- Superman - *obscured*
- Wonder Woman  - *obscured*
- Red Tornado - *obscured*
- Martian Manhunter - *obscured*
- The Flash (Barry Allen) - *obscured*
- Zatanna - *obscured*
- HawkMan - *obscured*
- The Atom - *obscured*
- Aquaman - *obscured*
- Green Arrow - *obscured*
- Black Canary - *obscured*

**[Top center framed image:](http://www.comicvine.com/images/1300-1640736)** - This represents the "Detroit" era of the Justice League. Following the destruction of the satellite headquarters, current League chairman Aquaman decided the League should only consist of full-time members; only the four previous members below remained, with four relative newcomers joining. Their new headquarters was in Detroit. This version of the League was active in *Justice League of America* (1960) 233-261, following their introduction in *Justice League of America Annual* #2 (which is where the image comes from).

- Zatanna
- Aquaman
- The Elongated Man
- Martian Manhunter
- Gypsy
- Steel
- Vibe
- Vixen - *obscured*

**[Top right framed image:](http://www.comicvine.com/images/1300-295266)** - This represents the version of the League seen in *Justice League* (1987) (The title changed to *Justice League International* with issue # 7, and *Justice League America* with issue #26). The image is from the cover of issue #1.

- Doctor Light,
- Oberon
- Blue Beetle
- Green Lantern (Guy Gardner)
- Mr. Miracle
- Batman
- Black Canary - *obscured*
- Doctor Fate - *obscured*
- Captain Marvel - *obscured*
- Martian Manhunter - *obscured*

**[Middle right framed image:](http://comicsalliance.com/files/2011/08/league11.jpg)** - This image represents the version of the Justice League from *JLA* (1997). Grant Morrison returned to the original 7 League members (or the characters who had taken over for them) as the core team for his run.

- Aquaman
- Martian Manhunter
- Batman
- Wonder Woman
- Superman
- Green Lantern (Kyle Rayner)  - *obscured*
- The Flash (Wally West) - *obscured*

~ Special thanks to [Mike Edenfield](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/mike-edenfield) for identifying Snapper Carr for me.

Comment: With such perseverance and attention to detail, I'm surprised you didn't qualify parenthetically that the foreground Green Lantern is Hal Jordan. Tsk tsk. I'd give you +infinity for this, but I can't...so +1.

Comment: Very complete! Actually the reason I didn't post this when I noticed the paintings, was that didn't recognise most of them. So I should +9 you.

Comment: What about the painting in the middle center? ;^)

Comment: Ach! I was going to do this! RARGH! Well done, Jack!

Comment: Just to be a bit more of a smartass, is there any reason to think these are paintings and not photos?

Comment: @Random832  I'll see your smartass comment, and raise you a nitpicking justification: of the five pictures on the wall, only the bottom right one matches the art style of the main figures standing in front, implying that the pictures are illustrations by in-universe artists rather than photographs.

Comment: But **which** Green Lantern's arm? D= We must know! (I second @Praxis on clarifying that the foreground is Hal Jordan.)

Comment: I like how this question went from a negative score yesterday to a positive one today because of Jack's answer.

Comment: @jpmc26 May your wish be granted. I also added all the characters who are being obscured due to either being covered by someone, or out of frame.

Comment: Really I dont know why I was downvote, I tried first to search who were these super heroes by the clothes and descriptions but I was struggling, but definitely Jack's answer is awesome.

Comment: Hmm... tempted to downvote because there are no links or numbered images.

Comment: @Omegacron there are links to the full images in the background, with the exception of the top left.

Comment: This really should be the chosen answer for the question.

Comment: @SplittingAdam It doesn't have to be, the accepted answer is correct for the question asked.

Comment: @JackBNimble But it's so thorough and it fills me with such geeky joy! And, really, Snapper Carr makes everything better.

Comment: @JackBNimble - still, though, I'm afraid there's just not enough detail here for an upvote.

Comment: @Omegacron You are dead to me.

Comment: The top-left image was used for the cover of ["Justice League of America Archives Volume 4"](http://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/justice-league-of-america-archives-vol-4), but I can't find where it was originally used (if anywhere). To find it, I snipped the picture (and GL's shoulder) and did a Google search using that image (after many tries trying to do an image search using keywords).

Comment: Is Martian Manhunter dead now, or did he just miss picture day for the first time in his life?

Comment: @Paul Interesting observation.

Comment: This is now the 8th highest-voted answer on the site. Kudos!

Comment: @JeanPaul: I suspect you were downvoted because you didn't tell in the question where the image came from.

Answer (score 17):

From left to right:

Top: Green Lantern, Wonder Woman, Superman, Batman, Black Canary

Bottom: Hawkgirl, Black Lightning, Speedy/Arsenal/Red Arrow, Vixen, Red Tornado.