# Who are all the people in this "BEST. SELFIE. EVER!"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, actor-identification

I gather that the people in this 'selfie' photograph have something to do with Star Trek, but I'm struggling to name them all.

[image]

Who are they?

Comment: `I'm struggling to name them all.` Did you bang your head or are you playing a game where you wait and see how long people take to call shenanigans on these claims? Cos I've got my broom ready.

Comment: @CrowTRobot - I'll be completely honest, I did recognise a few of them.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Most of them are easy for a serious Trekkie like yourself:

[image: here you go]
<sup>(picture with arrows found online)</sup>

But let's do this **properly**.

---

### The one you probably *didn't* know

The guy in the top right was the hardest to identify: his name is [**Patrick Baker**](https://twitter.com/BakerPatrickJ), owner of Farrell's Ice-cream Parlor and a celebrity handler for Wizard World Chicago, who was working at the Con that day as a 'celebrity handler'. Here's what he [said](http://uproxx.com/gammasquad/2014/08/a-star-trek-the-next-generation-selfie-gets-photobombed/) about the event:

> I’m the photo bomber. I’m a friend of the cast and I help them out at some conventions. Levar [Burton] took this photo as I was trying to herd them towards the stage door. Since I couldn’t duck fast enough, I decided to back up and commit to the photobomb.

Pics or it didn't happen? Here you go:

[image: Baker here]
[image: Baker]

---

### The short-changed Klingon

The small fraction of a face on the far right belongs to [**Michael Dorn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dorn), who played Worf in Star Trek TNG and DS9:

[image: Dorn here]
[image: Dorn]

Reference [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-2736506/Sir-Patrick-Stewart-Next-Generation-cast-super-Star-Trek-selfie-William-Shatner.html) for Dorn's presence if you can't see enough of him to believe it.

---

### The exotic half-human

The woman on the right is [**Marina Sirtis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marina_Sirtis), who played Deanna Troi in Star Trek TNG:

[image: Sirtis here] 
[image: Sirtis]

---

### The one who brought them together

The guy at the front, who gathered the others for this picture, is [**LeVar Burton**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LeVar_Burton), who played Geordi LaForge in Star Trek TNG:

[image: Burton here]
[image: Burton]

---

### The never-aging miracle

The bald guy just behind Burton to the left is [**Patrick Stewart**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Stewart), who played Jean-Luc Picard in Star trek TNG and doesn't seem to have aged a day since:

[image: Stewart here]
[image: Stewart]

---

### The bespectacled Number One

The guy on the far left is [**Jonathan Frakes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Frakes), who played William Riker in Star Trek TNG:

[image: Frakes here]
[image: Frakes]

---

### The venerable android

The white-haired guy just behind Stewart's head is [**Brent Spiner**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent_Spiner), who played Data, Lore and Nooniæn Soong in Star Trek TNG (as well as B4 in *Nemesis*) and Arik Soong in Star Trek Enterprise:

[image: Spiner here]
[image: Spiner]

---

### The ginger doctor

The woman at the back is [**Gates McFadden**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gates_McFadden), who played Beverley Crusher in Star Trek TNG and has kept her looks by ageing hardly more than Stewart:

[image: McFadden here]
[image: McFadden]

---

### The one from ages past

The square-faced man looking grumpy and confused is [**William Shatner**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shatner), who played James Kirk in Star Trek TOS (that's right, *TOS*!) and was brought through a temporal wormhole to join the TNG cast:

[image: Shatner here]
[image: Shatner]

---

### The passersby

The guy behind Frakes's head, and the owner of the patch of hair visible between Spiner and McFadden, are both currently **unidentified**. The [answer from @Praxis](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/104907/31394) confirms that even Patrick Baker isn't sure who they are.

Comment: You'd better change that from just Data to include me as well...

Comment: @N_Soong My apologies! Done :-)

Comment: @randal'thor : *Please* tell me you're actually going to start watching Star Trek now!  :-)

Comment: Wait, if you're going to add that, shouldn't Lore make the cut? (And I forget, did Riker's teleportation double get a name, the googles suggest Tom)

Comment: What about that *other* other guy in the background??

Comment: You forgot the [Freehand Circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/252593)

Comment: @Praxis I've been planning to give it a try for a while; the trouble is getting hold of the damn thing!

Comment: Wow, Frakes got old.

Comment: BUT WHO IS THE GUY IN THE TOP-LEFT LOOKING DOWN THE HALL!!!

Comment: Is there such a thing as -1 for overkill?

Comment: Poor Marina Sirtis.  Time has been much less kind to her than the other cast members...

Comment: @ThePopMachine [Nope](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100281/31394).

Comment: @RussellBorogove [I didn't invent it](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100020/is-it-noonien-or-noonian-soong#comment230425_100020)!

Comment: There is a wider version of this that includes all of Dorn's face.

Comment: Why is Riker's arrow a slightly different colour?

Comment: @Richard Ask whoever made that picture - it wasn't me!

Comment: Dude......time has not been kind to Sirtis. Wow

Answer (score 30):

## The top-left corner guy likely works for the Rosemont Theatre.

[image]

Here's that photo again, taken right from **rand al'thor**'s answer (which he took from a preexisting web article), and for completeness I'll say that the top-right guy is celebrity handler **Patrick J. Baker** — also see rand al'thor's answer for the details.

The real mystery is the guy in the top-left corner.  I asked Patrick Baker directly.

- [Twitter Messages](https://mobile.twitter.com/BakerPatrickJ/status/653391065806974976)

> **@RemnantsOfPraxis:** If you're talking about the guy in white behind Frakes head, I don't know.  He may have worked for the theater.

The theatre in question is the **Rosemont Theatre** (where Chicago Comic Con 2014 was held).

I tried to find a staff listing for the theatre in hopes of comparing, but I couldn't find one, and even if there were, it probably wouldn't include non-administrative personnel.

Comment: +1 from me for original research & going "above and beyond".

Comment: Nice one Praxis! I also contacted Patrick Baker, but I don't have a Twitter account, so you got a response quicker :-) Looks like the final answer will be "don't know", as I suspected.